# Login e dados null php

Tags: php

estou com um problema com a função de login e perfil.
O que eu entendi dos testes foi que quando é dado um var_dump na $_SESSION mostra um array que vem NULL e outro com as informações. Tem como ter 2 sessões diferentes ? Pois renomeando uma das sessões para $_SESSION2 (não sei se pode)
pega apenas um array com as informações. Mas ainda sim na verificação da pagina perfil as informações chega naquela verificação NULL mesmo pegando todos os campos (debuguei o código e parece que não manda as informações pro perfil.php).

Na código se eu colocar var_dump ($_SESSION); var_dump ($senha); var_dump ($users); exit; depois do session_start(); e antes de 
colocar as variaveis na $_SESSION me retorna 2 do mesmo array sendo um deles NULL e outro com os dados corretos também e não fala 
que tenho variaveis indefinidas, porém, colocando os "var_dump" depois fala que minhas variaveis são null

````
<?php

include("conexao.php");
//require '../PDO/init.php';


// inclui o arquivo de inicialização
//require '../PDO/init.php';

// resgata variáveis do formulário
$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : '';
$senha = isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha'] : '';

//se estiver vazio
 if (empty($nome) && empty($senha))
 {

  //header("Location: ../pages/perfil.php");
    echo "Informe email e senha";
    exit;
}


$sql = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM cadastrotime WHERE nome=:NOME AND senha=:SENHA");
 /*var_dump ($senha);
 exit;*/

$sql->bindParam(':NOME', $nome);
$sql->bindParam(':SENHA', $senha);

$sql->execute();

$users = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($users); echo "</pre>";

if (count($users) <= 0)
{ /*var_dump ($senha);
  exit;*/
    header("Location: ../pages/login.php");
    echo "nome ou senha incorretos";
    exit;
}

// pega o primeiro usuário

//echo "<pre>"; print_r($users); echo "</pre>";
/*var_dump ($users);
exit;*/  

session_start();
/*var_dump ($_SESSION);
var_dump ($senha);
var_dump ($users);
exit;*/ /* AQUI RETORNA 2 ARRAY UM DELES SENDO NULL */
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = true;
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $users['id'];
$_SESSION['user_nome'] = $users['nome'];
$_SESSION['user_email'] = $users['email'];
$_SESSION['user_senha'] = $users['senha'];
$_SESSION['user_nomeLider'] = $users['nomeLider'];
$_SESSION['user_pais'] = $users['pais'];
$_SESSION['user_qtdJogador'] = $users['qtdJogador'];
$_SESSION['user_cpf'] = $users['cpf'];
$_SESSION['user_membro1'] = $users['membro1'];
$_SESSION['user_membro2'] = $users['membro2'];
$_SESSION['user_membro3'] = $users['membro3'];
$_SESSION['user_membro4'] = $users['membro4'];
$_SESSION['user_membro5'] = $users['membro5'];
//echo "<pre>"; print_r($users); echo "</pre>";
/*var_dump ($_SESSION);
var_dump ($senha);
var_dump ($users);
exit;*/ /* AQUI RETORNA 2 ARRAY UM DELES SENDO NULL E FALANDO "Undefined index: "variavel" in "meu arquivo"*/




header('Location: ../pages/perfilTime.php');

?>  
```  
aqui o meu html só com o formulário
```    
<?php
//session_start();
include("../PDO/conexao.php");
require_once '../PDO/init.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user_nome']) && !isset($_SESSION['user_senha']) )
var_dump($_SESSION['user_nome']);
var_dump($_SESSION['user_senha']);
exit;
//header("location:../pages/index.php");

?>


        <!-- FORMULARIO DE EDIÇÃO -->


        <div class ="formulario">
        <form method="POST" action="../PDO/alteraTime.php">
        <div class="card">      
            <div class="card-body">
              <h4 class="card-title">Painel de edição do Time</h4>
              <p>Bem-vindo ao seu painel, <?php echo $_SESSION['user_nome']; ?> | <a href="../PDO/logout.php">Sair</a></p>
              <!-- ../PDO/logout.php -->
                <p class="card-description">
                  Basic form layout
                </p>

            <form class="forms-sample">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputEmail1">NOME</label>

                <input type="text" name="nome" class="form-control" value="<?php  echo $_SESSION['user_nome'];?>">

              </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">EMAIL</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" value="<?php  echo $_SESSION['user_email'];?>">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputPassword1">SENHA</label>
                <input type="text" name="senha" class="form-control" id="senha" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_senha'];?>">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Nome do Líder</label>
                <input type="text" name="cpf" class="form-control" id="cpf" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_nomeLider']?>">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Pais de origem</label>
                <input type="text" name="cpf" class="form-control" id="cpf" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_pais']?>">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Quatidade de jogadores</label>
                <input type="text" name="cpf" class="form-control" id="cpf" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_qtdJogador']?>">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">CPF do Líder</label>
                <input type="text" name="cel" class="form-control" id="cel" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_cpf']?>">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Membro 1 do time</label>
                <input type="text" name="cel" class="form-control" id="cel" value="<?php $_SESSION['user_membro1']?>">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Membro 2 do time</label>
                <input type="text" name="cel" class="form-control" id="cel" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_membro2']?>">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Membro 3 do time</label>
                <input type="text" name="cel" class="form-control" id="cel" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_membro3']?>">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Membro 4 do time</label>
                <input type="text" name="cel" class="form-control" id="cel" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_membro4']?>">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Membro 5 do time</label>
                <input type="text" name="cel" class="form-control" id="cel" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_membro5']?>">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-2">CONFIRMAR</button>

              <button class="btn btn-light">CANCELAR</button>
              </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- FIM FORMULÁRIO -->


``
````

Comment: no lugar de fetchAll use apenas fetch que irá trazer apenas o primeiro registro ja que se trata de login e senha, teste e se não der certo você chama o array usando numero, exemplo: ao inves de $users['id'] use $users[0] etc, para fazer o teste

Comment: Já descobri o erro, eu esqueci de setar para fazer a busca $users = $sql->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)[0]; para retornar apenas a primeira linha que as informações do consulta da query bater